# How to update data into a file in a particular position in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, fs

I have a file with the data as follows,

```
Test.txt,
  <template class="get" type="amp-mustache">
      <div class="divcenter">
/////Need to append data at this point/////
      </div>
  </template>
```

I have the data like below

```
[ 
  {'text':'<p>grapes</p>'},
  {'text':'<p>banana</p>'},   
  {'text':'<p>orange</p>'},
  {'text':'<p>apple</p>'},
  {'text':'<p>gua</p>'}
]
```

After appending the data should be,

```
  <template class="get">
      <div class="divcenter">
        <p>grapes</p>
        <p>banana</p>   
        <p>orange</p>
        <p>apple</p>
        <p>gua</p>
      </div>
  </template>
```

My code,

```
fs.readFile(Test.txt, function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
           throw err;
     }
   var file_content = data.toString();
   var c = file_content.indexOf(' <div class="divcenter">');
});
```

But how can I append after finding the index?

Comment: Try using some parser like https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom and why did you tagged angularjs :)

Comment: Hi codtex as this related to js,some experts like could come form angular js...:)

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this :

- find the index where you want to insert your string
- slice the source string and insert new string

  ```
  fs.readFile(Test.txt, function read(err, data) {
     if (err) {
        throw err;
     }
     var file_content = data.toString();
     var str = "<p>grapes</p>
             <p>banana</p>   
             <p>orange</p>
             <p>apple</p>
             <p>gua</p>";
     var idx = file_content.indexOf('<div class="divcenter">') + '<div class="divcenter">'.length;
     var result = file_content.slice(0, idx) + str + file_content.slice(idx);
  });
  ```

Answer (score -1):

This is not the most elegant way with using only `substr`

```
var needle = '<div class="divcenter">';
var newString = file_content.substr(0, c + needle.length)
    + '__NEW_STRING__' 
    + file_content.substr(needle.length - 1);
```

**Edit:**

A more elegant way is to traverse the string as DOM using [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

Answer (score -1):

Why not do in jquery.

Use for loop to do it like this:

```
var uiDiv = $(".divcenter");
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
   uiDiv.append("<p>'"+data[i]+"'</p>");
}
```

Hope it works.