# How to write into a file at particular position in node js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, fs

I want to write to a file at particular position.

```
    <p>
    <div class="divcenter">
    </div>
   </p>
```

I want to write elements in my ['p','a',b'] in between divcenter as follows

```
<p>
 <div class="divcenter">
    p
    a
    b
 </div>
 </p>
```

my file,

```
  array.forEach(function(i,v) {
         fs.readFile(listBlogsFile, function read(err, listData) {
                if (err) {
                    helper.logs('prepareAmpFilesFromList','blog',err,'console'); 
                    throw err;
                }
                var modListData = listData.toString(),
                c = modListData.indexOf('<div class="divcenter">'),
                position = c + 25;
                console.log(c); 
                var file = fs.openSync(listBlogsFile, 'r+');
                var bufferedText = new Buffer(i);
                fs.writeSync(file, bufferedText, 0, bufferedText.length, position);
            }); 
      });
```

Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update data into a file in a particular position in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564373/how-to-update-data-into-a-file-in-a-particular-position-in-js)